# Android: Take video without user input

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if there was a way to record video without user input in android. I've tried to to use other code before, but it pops up the camera app which is not what I want.

Comment: What other code did you use?

Comment: androidexamplwe.com/Camera_Video_Capture_And_Save_On_SDCard_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=123&aaid=143

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are welcome to use `MediaRecorder`, in conjunction with `android.hardware.Camera` or the `android.hardware.camera2.*` classes, to record a video, without the user having to do anything other than run your app.

Using an `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` `Intent` to launch a third-party video recorder will usually require that the user tap something to start recording the video.